# Windows 8 - Custom Live Tile

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

We are developing an app for Windows 8 in C#.

Our app involves drawings the user creates, and we'd like to incorporate their drawings into the live tile.

I have found examples of setting text and pictures as your app's live tile.  Is there a way to do custom stuff to render lines, etc.?

Or is the only way to do what we need by rendering a PNG out to our app's AppData directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to render a PNG or JPG into the apps data directory. The live tile has  a fixed number of pre-defined templates and outside of that all you can do is pick the template with a full-tile image and supply your own image.

Comment: P.S. the image can also be embedded in your appx, but obviously that wouldn't be dynamic. Here's a good article on loading custom images into tiles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465432.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid this was the only way.  Is there an image rendering API you'd recommend?  Last time I've had to render out images was back in System.Drawing days.

Comment: I think I'm just going to define our tiles in Xaml, then render them out doing something like this: http://mcoxeter.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/render-xaml-to-image/

Comment: `RenderTargetBitmap` not available in metro...  So new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180235/windows-8-metro-app-render-pngs

Comment: Sorry I took so long to reply to this. You might want to check out http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/.