# Windows 8 Metro App - Render PNGs

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am needing to render some custom PNGs in a Windows 8 app.

Basically I need to create a custom live tile by putting some drawings made in my app on top of an image for a live tile, and the only way to do this is render a PNG to disk, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149591/windows-8-custom-live-tile).

What library should I use to do this?  My first thought was to use a Xaml `UserControl` and `RenderTargetBitmap`, but it is not available in a Metro app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinRT XAML Toolkit has some extension methods for WriteableBitmap that you could use too. You could probably use [WriteableBitmapLoadExtensions](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17730#327689) for loading and [WriteableBitmapSaveExtensions](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17730#327690) for saving. It has a fairly limited blitting capability though since that is exposed by [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) already and simple to write anyway. [WriteableBitmapBlitBlockExtensions](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17730#327681) is only a method to blit a full width block of pixels from bitmaps of same width.

Edit* `RenderTargetBitmap` is now available in Windows 8.1. It doesn't support some elements though (I think it doesn't render camera previews, media elements and perhaps `WebViews`).

Comment: I actually ended up taking some extensions from there to save out to a PNG file.  Are there any extensions to render lines?  Or even render other images at angles to create lines?  I got my case working with `WriteableBitmapEx` but the lines are very ugly compared to what is rendered in our game.

Comment: I think you would need to either look into Direct2D or implement your own antialiased line drawing methods.

Comment: We are using MonoGame, so I will see if `RenderTarget2D` will work.  Last I checked `RenderTarget2D` didn't work in MonoGame (on iOS).  I will try it for Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only option is to use DirectX (or SharpDX) to create your image. You'll probably have to recreate the drawing using the low-level DirectX APIs.
[WritableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) might also be helpful if your drawings are simple.

Comment: WriteableBitmapEx look's like it is what I'm looking for.  I can see where I can render an image and draw lines on top of it.  Are there any examples of saving out to disk?

Comment: I don't have any sample here but you'll want to use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx

Comment: That is what the extensions from the WinRT Xaml Toolkit use.  So an example is here for those needing it: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17730#327690