# Change background color of the tile programatically?

Tags: microsoft-metro

I understand the background is actually an image (WideLogo.png/SmallLogo.png) and specified in the app manifest file. But is it possible to swap these with a new set of images programatically? Based on the information displayed on the tile, I want to change the background color of the tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot edit the app manifest to change the default color. However, you can render an image with the appropriate background color and content then set it as tile.

For more details on how to achieve that, read: [Windows 8 Metro App - Render PNGs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180235/windows-8-metro-app-render-pngs)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the background color of the tile programmatically. That's set in the manifest for the default tile, so that you can overlay a transparent background image for a predictable default look for your tile.

But you can send tile notifications from your app while running, and these can include images and text.

Here's a link to the MSDN docs on tiles and notifications:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779724.aspx

and to the catalog of tile templates you can use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx

One way you could implement this is to programmatically create a tile image with the background color and text you want, and then send that as a tile notification.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm already using tile and notifications with templates. I want to be able to change the background without using the notifications.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to change your app's tile is using notifications, either locally, or using the WNS for push notifications.