# Can I create my own Live Tile XML template?

Tags: xml, windows-8, live-tile

I am currently developing the live tile functionality for our sparkling new Windows 8 app. However, I've gotten some pretty specific designs for this live tile, and there isn't any of the [tile templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761491.aspx) that can be tweaked to make it look like it should.

Is there any way to create a custom XML-template for a tile, and if so, how would you implement animations etc for it?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: Even though I know I could make a webservice create a custom design on an image and link that up, I'd rather not go down that road due to time constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not.

But you can generate an image. It is not needed to be server-side [Windows 8 - Custom Live Tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149591/windows-8-custom-live-tile)

Comment: I know there is a possibility that I can solve things that way - but that wouldn't animate correctly. Thanks however :-)